# Too many TypeScript compiler instances

Tags: typescript, tsc

Now that I have a number of reasonably sized TypeScript libraries and apps I have noticed that builds reduce my multi-core 8Gb dev machine to a crawl.  The cause is the large number of TypeScript compiler instances spun up by VS2012 when I do a build.

I presume I must have a stupid VS2012/TypeScript setting somewhere.  Any suggestions?

Comment: And the answer is make sure the switch 'Build all TypeScript files on build ' is false.

Comment: You should add the solution as an answer so that people know this question has been answered.

Answer (score 0):

i had created a _reference.ts file in root and referred all my ts files over there,something like this

```
/// <reference path="app/logic/init/init.ts" />


  /// <reference path="app/logic/controllers/profilecontoller.ts" />
 /// <reference path="app/logic/directives/directives.ts" />
 /// <reference path="app/logic/enums/enums.ts" />


/// <reference path="app/logic/init/bootstrap.ts" />
```